# Calling a member function with one parameter (bound) for each object in a container

Tags: c++, algorithm, numeric, mem-fun, bind2nd

I have a

```
using namespace std;
typedef vector<Coil*> CoilVec;
CoilVec Coils;
```

with `Coil` being a base class for `CilCoil` and `RectCoil`, a cilindrical coil and a rectangular coil, respectively. Now I wish to invoke a member function `calcField` on each `Coil` pointed to in `Coils`. This member function is purely virtual in the base class but has been implemented in the derived classes and its declaration looks like this:

```
virtual TVector3 calcField(const TVector3&);
```

with `TVector3` being the 3D vector class from the RooT library. The idea now is to calculate the field of every `Coil` in `Coils` and add them together. Since the argument of `calcField` (namely a vector to the position in which to calculate the field) would be the same for every call, I would like to use an STL algorithm from the `<algorithm>` or `<numeric>` header to do something like this (imagined):

```
using namespace std;
typedef vector<Coil*>::const_iterator CoilIt;
const TVector3& P(1.,1.,1.); // Let's say we want to know the total field in (1,1,1)
TVector3 B; // Default initialization: (0,0,0)
CoilIt begin = Coils.begin();
CoilIt end = Coils.end();
B = accumulate(begin, end, B, bind2nd(mem_fun(&Coil::calcField), P));
```

Obviously, since I'm here to ask a question, this doesn't seem to work. So my question is quite simply put: why does this not work and/or how would you go about doing it the right way (within the limits of the STL)?

I get the following error messages trying to compile the above (the file I'm working in is called Interface.cpp, it's third-party code):

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.5/numeric:62:0,
                from Interface.cpp:7: /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_numeric.h: In function ‘_Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Coil* const*, std::vector<Coil*> >, _Tp = TVector3, _BinaryOperation = std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<TVector3, Coil, const TVector3&> >]’:
Interface.cpp:289:72: instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_numeric.h:150:2: error: no match for call to ‘(std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<TVector3, Coil, const TVector3&> >) (TVector3&, Coil* const&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/backward/binders.h:147:7: note: candidates are: typename _Operation::result_type std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(const typename _Operation::first_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::mem_fun1_t<TVector3, Coil, const TVector3&>, typename _Operation::result_type = TVector3, typename _Operation::first_argument_type = Coil*]
/usr/include/c++/4.5/backward/binders.h:153:7: note:                  typename _Operation::result_type std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(typename _Operation::first_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::mem_fun1_t<TVector3, Coil, const TVector3&>, typename _Operation::result_type = TVector3, typename _Operation::first_argument_type = Coil*]
```

Comment: Not going to give this as an answer as you asked for something within the STL, but have you considered the Boost libraries (specifically boost::bind)? I was having the same problem switching over fixed it.

Comment: Sounds like you want `for_each`, not `accumulate`.

Comment: `Coils` is a type, not an object, so `Coils.begin()` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @chameco: I have considered it, but I'd rather stick to the STL in this case.

Comment: @Wouter No, you really shouldn't. The `bind1st` and `bind2nd` have been deprecated for a reason. What you want is impossible with them.

Comment: @pmr That's too bad, I was hoping to avoid using boost since I'm not yet familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `std::accumulate()` has to be a binary function, each call to the function will be given two parameters (the already accumulated value and the next element of the vector).

The bound function you pass to `std::accumulate()` only takes one parameter, a `Coil*`. To be used with `accumulate`, it would have to take two parameters (`Vector3D` and `Coil*`).

Answer (score 0):

The result of your `bind2nd` call is a unary function that takes a `Coli*`. `std::accumulate` expects a binary function that can be called with the accumulator and the current value, i.e. it wants a function that takes `(TVector3, Coli*)`.

It seems like what you're trying to do is transform each `Coli*` to a `TVector3` and then accumulate the results.

You could do this with an explicit `std::transform` step to fill a `vector<TVector3>` and then use `std::accumulate`, or you could write a separate free function that takes `(TVector3 t1, TVector3 t2, Coli* c)`, returns `t2 + c->calcField(t1)`, then use `bind1st` on that to get your binary accumulator function.

If you want to do it without writing a separate free function, you'll need `boost::bind` or C++11.

Comment: This actually compiles! I still have to run some tests to check if it does what I want it to do, but I'm hopeful :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not worth the trouble to get your code to compile with `mem_fun`, `bind2nd` and friends. I would strongly suggest writing a good old-fashioned loop instead:

```
for (CoilIt it = coils.begin(); it != coils.end(); ++it)
{
    B += (**it).calcField(P);
}
```

Comment: This will probably be my temporary solution until I have a deeper look into boost. Still, I'd like to avoid for-loops, even when they appear to be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a nested bind. Those are incredibly hard to do with
the deprecated binders. Here is a simplified example with `boost::bind`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct A {
  double foo(double d) { return d; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<A> vs;
  double d = 0.0;
  d = std::accumulate(begin(vs), end(vs), d, 
                      boost::bind(std::plus<double>(), _1, 
                                  boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(&A::foo), _2, 0.0)));
  return 0;
}
```

I believe your misunderstanding is that you assume accumulate uses
`operator+` to accumulate the result of the functor you pass in. In
fact the functor is used to accumulate the result. This is based on
the general concept of a `fold` in functional programming.

The functor you pass in must be of the form

```
Ret func(const T1& a, const T2& b)
```

where Ret must be convertible to T (the type of the `init` parameter),
`T1` must be such that `T` can be implicitly converted to it and `T2`
must be such that the result of dereferencing an iterator into the
sequence must be implicitly convertible to it.

Comment: I'll have to work up some knowledge of boost to really understand this then. We should be taking a look at the boost library in my C++ course on tuesday. Hopefully that will help clear things up. But as I said in a comment on my question: I was hoping an STL solution was possible, at least for now.

Comment: @Wouter C++11 has `std::bind` which is just a standardized version of `boost::bind`. The code above should be nearly 100% compatible with it. If you have a recent compiler, go with it. Then again, you will probably use a lamdba to do this with a recent compiler.